# Dynamically call dataservice in different modules depending on object type WPF MVVM c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, module

What is the best way to call dataservices and organise a modular project in WPF ?

I am pretty new in MVVM and WPF and I have a project with at least :

- 1 main "organizer" module
- 10 independant modules (whose are loaded or not)
- A dataservice in each module to do some operation with my data

I want to know if they are a way to call my module dataservice from my main organizer module dynamically without using a super_long_switch_case_of_death_with_redondant_code. What is the best way to achive this ?

For exemple, when I click on one of my item (in a treeview), I call a command which execute this function :

```
private void AddNewThingsCommand(object myObject)
{
        if (myObject== null) return;

        var objectType = myObject.GetType().ToString();
        switch (objectType)
        {

            case "FirstObjectType":

                ModuleFirst.Services.ModuleFirstDataService moduleFirstDataService = new ModuleFirst.Services.ModuleFirstDataService ();
  moduleFirstDataService.DoSomeSuperActionInMyDataService(someObject);
                break;
            case "SecondObjectType":

                ModuleSecond.Services.ModuleSecondDataService ModuleSecondDataService = new ModuleSecond.Services.ModuleSecondDataService ();
  ModuleSecondDataService.DoSomeRandomSuperActionInMyDataService(someObject2);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

 }
```

But it seem to be really repetitive and useless stuff to do, have you any idea how to automatize that ?

I don't need a [WPF Trigger based on Object Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652341/wpf-trigger-based-on-object-type)  I am looking for something I can use in a command to dynamically load my services and get items throught my modules.

Answer (score 0):

For Factory , I have normally used MEF. Instead of concrete implementations, try to use combination of Interface and MEF framework.

**About MEF:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/