# Different colors for each ListViewItem based on type (WPF XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, styling

I'm struggling with a school project. I'm making a very basic application, that can read the content of a selected folder and display it in a ListView. I've created an interface called IFiles and have three sub-classes named: Image, Text and Folder. They all implement the IFiles interface.

My problem is mostly regarding the design in XAML. Because I want each listview item to have it's own individual color based on what type of object it finds. So if its a Text file, the background color should be green, and if its an image it should be blue. My current solution partially works, but it does paint the entire row as I want it to.

I can indeed choose a color for the ListViewItem, but I only know how to do it for all at once, not for a single row.

This is my code:

```
   <Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="ImgIcon" UriSource="/Images/photo.png" DecodePixelHeight="20" DecodePixelWidth="20"></BitmapImage>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="TextIcon" UriSource="/Images/textfile.png" DecodePixelHeight="20" DecodePixelWidth="20"></BitmapImage>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Image}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Blue" >
            <Image Source="{DynamicResource ImgIcon}"></Image>
            <Label Content="Filename:"></Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
            <Label Content="Size:"></Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding Size}"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Text}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Green" >
            <Image Source="{DynamicResource TextIcon}"></Image>
            <Label Content="Filename:"></Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
            <Label Content="Size:"></Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding Size}"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Load Folder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="315,355,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="40" Command="{Binding LoadFolderCMD}"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" Margin="0,0,0,89" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="792"/>

</Grid>
```

This is what it looks like when I execute it:

[image: Execution of the program]

The red part should have the same color as the content inside of the particular row.

Hope you can help me

Comment: Your data templates are almost same. I'd suggest you to use only one data template and choose the color based on the item type, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4965683/2846483). Then, you can set up a style for the whole `ListViewItem` - instead of hard-coded red color it will use the color based on the item type.

Answer (score 0):

Set HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" on the ListView.

You should also take advantage of grid rows and columns to confine items into separate areas. Avoid using margins for placement, the margins and paddings should be used for defining gap between elements, not their absolute position.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `ItemTemplate` fill the available space by setting the `HorizontalContentAlignment` of the `ListViewItem` to `Stretch` and move some padding from it to the data templates:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
</Style>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Image}">
    <Border Background="Blue" Padding="4,1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{DynamicResource ImgIcon}"></Image>
            <Label Content="Filename:"></Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
            <Label Content="Size:"></Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding Size}"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Text}">
    <Border Background="Green" Padding="4,1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{DynamicResource TextIcon}"></Image>
            <Label Content="Filename:"></Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
            <Label Content="Size:"></Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding Size}"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: @Lukas Méndez Duus: Did you try this?